# Integration of IE9 in Vista SP2 fails with error 0x8007000e

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-9, unattended

I try to deploy Windows Vista SP2 with MDT, and to integrate all updates and Internet Explorer 9.

While updates are successfully installed, I'm unable to add KB982861 package. Windows setup stops on "Installing update" step and `setuperr.log` contains the following:

```
2014-02-21 19:43:45, Error                 CSI    00004701 (F) STATUS_NO_MEMORY #67245051# from `anonymous-namespace'::ChangeListOrderingContext::LoadAndParseOrderFile(...)[gle=0xd0000017]
2014-02-21 19:43:45, Error                 CSI    00004702 (F) STATUS_NO_MEMORY #67059342# from Windows::COM::CPendingTransaction::ExtractInformationFromRtlTransaction(...)[gle=0xd0000017]
2014-02-21 19:43:45, Error                 CSI    00004703 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14) #66489137# from Windows::COM::CPendingTransaction::IStorePendingTransaction_Analyze(...)[gle=0x8007000e]
2014-02-21 19:43:46, Error                 CSI    00004704 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14) #66481927# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_Commit(Flags = 102 (0x00000066), pSink = NULL, disp = disp, coldpatching = FALSE)[gle=0x8007000e]
2014-02-21 19:43:46, Error                 CSI    00004705 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14) #66481926# 113299006 us from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction_ICSITransaction::Commit(flags = 0x00000066, pSink = NULL, disp = 0)
[gle=0x8007000e]
2014-02-21 19:43:46, Error                 CBS    Exec: Failed to commit CSI transaction to execute changes. hr: 0x8007000e
2014-02-21 19:43:46, Error                 CBS    Pkgmgr: Failed unattend install: Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Package-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~9.1.8112.16421, hr: 0x8007000e

2014-02-21 19:46:24, Error      [0x0604a7] IBS    InstantiateCBSUnattendPass: Package manager returned with failing exit code 14
2014-02-21 19:46:24, Error      [0x060431] IBS    Callback_UnattendInitiatePass: An error occurred while initiating unattend passes; hr = 0x80004005
```

System is HP Compaq dc8580 with 1GB RAM. IE 9 prerequisites packages are also installed.

How could I fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `0x8007000e` is due to lack of memory. Upgrading from 1GB to 2GB resolved the issue.